# How to retrieve answer from sendfile_osm_oauth_protector

Tags: python, openstreetmap, authentication

I made a request by using the [enter link description here](https://github.com/geofabrik/sendfile_osm_oauth_protector)sendfile_osm_oauth_protector

```
from subprocess import check_output

command = "curl -b 'text from cookie_output_file' https://osm- 
    internal.download.geofabrik.de/asia/philippines-latest-internal.osm.pbf"
out = check_output(command)
```

how do I find the link to download in this output? it is like a complex text.

Answer (score 0):

I found it by using bs4.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(out, "html.parser")

for item in soup.find_all("a"):
    if "osm-internal" in item['href']:
        print(item['href'])
```